# popup window from right on the page load through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i searched on internet for j Query or java script code that do some work for me like when the the page completely loads a popup window come out from the right side for some time and then disappears after some specific time but i couldn't succeed. i need yours help and favor in this regard.(send me any link of document related my question or any you tube or any other media link from where i could get help now and for future).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery' anitmate function [Animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

some thing like this: pseudocode

```
$('#yourDivorModalBox').animate({
    right: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked jQuery's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function? There's also [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    newwindow = window.open('http://www.google.com/','testme','height=200,width=300');
});
```

Then use [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to close the popup.